# Elasticsearch Service with Cognito -- how to access via Python HTTP request

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I recently setup an Elasticsearch service and configured it to use Cognito for identify management. I followed [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-cognito-auth.html) and so far everything is working exactly as expected. I'm able to add new users as expected, and they can access Kibana as expected.

However, I would also like to use Python to interact with the Elasticsearch service. I've following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-python), but I get permission errors about not having the right access.

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import boto3

host = 'hostname.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/'
region = 'us-east-2'
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = [{'host': host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth = awsauth,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = True,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection
)

print(es.info())
```

```
AuthorizationException: AuthorizationException(403, 'security_exception', 'no permissions for [indices:admin/get] and User [name=arn:aws:iam::12345678:user/username, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]')
```

I'm not sure if the issue is related to the way that I have Conginto configured, or if it's related to the way that I'm submitting this request.  Any help on figuring out where my issue might be would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you disable/remove congito authetication and try without it. Also what policy to you have on your ES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me too. There are two ways I found, you have to create an IAM user for both of them.

- Open IAM console and give necessary policies to IAM user for reaching your elasticsearch domain (or I attached "AdministratorAccess" policy only (It gives all access of AWS)),  then you should use credentials of this IAM account.
- Or open kibana -> security -> roles -> click all_access role -> mapped_users -> manage_mapping. Then you should add arn of your IAM user to backend roles. You have to use this user's credentials not "boto3.Session().get_credentials()" on your code to connect ES.
  I suggest the second one if you are not familiar with IAM roles and policies.

[image: You should go to this page in kibana:]

[image: You can create credentials for IAM user using this button]